# Is there any way to force node/npm to use globally installed modules, if both global and local versions exist?

Tags: node.js, npm

As I understand it, if a NPM module is installed both globally and locally, then the local version is the one that will get used.

Is there any way to force use of the global version, if both exist?

Comment: What's the reason to do this? - just curious.

Comment: did you try npm install --force ? Is that what you want?

Comment: Just delete your local module, it'll automatically go up in the global module's directory to look for the required module.

Comment: i think if you uninstall local package and run app after that install local again it will keep using global package